# $expand=manager does not expand manager

Tags: odata, microsoft-graph-api

When testing `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<my-email>/manager`, I receive the following response (I replaced values with "HIDDEN"):

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#directoryObjects/$entity",
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
    "id": HIDDEN,
    "businessPhones": [
        HIDDEN
    ],
    "displayName": HIDDEN,
    "givenName": HIDDEN,
    "jobTitle": "Director, Information Technology",
    "mail": HIDDEN,
    "mobilePhone": HIDDEN,
    "officeLocation": HIDDEN,
    "preferredLanguage": null,
    "surname": HIDDEN,
    "userPrincipalName": HIDDEN
}
```

Clearly it works. But when I try the same URI using `$expand` instead, it doesn't show the manager:

URI: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<my-email>?$expand=manager`

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
    "businessPhones": [
        HIDDEN
    ],
    "displayName": "Yousef Shanawany",
    "givenName": "Yousef",
    "jobTitle": "Developer, Application",
    "mail": HIDDEN,
    "mobilePhone": null,
    "officeLocation": "US California San Jose America Center",
    "preferredLanguage": null,
    "surname": "Shanawany",
    "userPrincipalName": HIDDEN,
    "id": HIDDEN
}
```

How can I get my manager using the `$expand` parameter in MS Graph?

Answer (score 3):

I believe this works in beta today. Try `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me?$expand=manager`

Comment: This actually worked. Thank you very much. In their documentation, it does say manager is expandable but doesn't mention it's only for beta, so IDK if I should mark your beneficial answer as a solution or not.

Comment: This is documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?toc=.%2Fref%2Ftoc.json&view=graph-rest-1.0#expand-parameter: "With Azure AD resources that derive from directoryObject, like user and group, $expand is only supported for beta and typically returns a maximum of 20 items for the expanded relationship."